# Make C++98 and C++03 tags synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems like these tags are now both effectively synonyms for "C++ before C++11".

The differences between C++98 and C++03 are very small. I suspect almost no one using the C++03 tag really does mean "C++03 and *not* C++98". I caught myself using `C++98` and `C++03` in separate questions when in both cases I only meant to express "not C++11".

Even major compilers don't don't distinguish between the two.

It would be helpful if the downvoters offered commentary. The major objection I can see is that one might need to ask questions when writing code for compilers that don't implement the 03 corrections but if that's the case I would say the appropriate tag is the compiler.

**Update** Based on the ensuing discussion I actually did open a question that makes meaningful distinction between C++98 and C++03. It of course uses both tags.

[Is value initialization part of the C++98 standard? If not, why was it added in the C++03 standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349679/is-value-initialization-part-of-the-c98-standard-if-not-why-was-it-added-in)

I guess that disproves my OP.

**Update 2** remyabel opened this interesting question:

[In GCC, Clang and MSVC is there any way to conform against C++98 and not C++03?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356712/in-gcc-clang-and-msvc-is-there-any-way-to-conform-against-c98-and-not-c03)

Comment: I thought `-std=c++98` and `-std=c++03` did the same thing. Can you point me to the relevant documentation for either one?

Comment: The manpage for g++ lists `c++98` and `c++03` as two headings for the same paragraph. (Edit: Just so you don't think I'm crazy, someone deleted some comments I was replying to.)

Comment: [Is C++03 a new version of the C++ Standard or just a Technical Corrigendum (TC) of C++98?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285777/is-c03-a-new-version-of-the-c-standard-or-just-a-technical-corrigendum-tc) seems to settle the debate in your favor.

Comment: @BartoszKP Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think I see what @BartoszKP means. The linked question isn't quite conclusive.

Comment: n1 :) Perhaps you should now edit the title to be the opposite? ;)

Comment: antonyms?? well that'd just be weird!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when I don't want to refer to [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) or [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) I simply tag as [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). However, there are some like [Mike Seymour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188590/conditionally-enforce-template-types-in-c#comment42863849_27188590) who may assume C++11 from [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) alone:

> @ikh The question isn't tagged C++11, so I wouldn't make a big fuss
>   over C++11 features. –  remyabel
>
> @remyabel: It's tagged C++, which these days means C++11 (or possibly
>   14, I'm not sure whether that's officially the standard yet). –  Mike
>   Seymour
>
> @Mike I think C++14 has been ratified, but does that mean
>   C++14 should be assumed? I don't think so. –  remyabel
>
> @remyabel: I think so, although the best answers will mention when
>   they use new features, and suggest workarounds for those stuck in the
>   past. That's just my opinion though. –  Mike Seymour

Of course, it would be disingenuous to omit information such as "use smart pointers" or "use <random> instead of rand()" even if the question isn't tagged C++11, unless the user is specifically asking for a pre-C++11 solution. Then the C++03 tag will clarify that.

For the longest time, I mistakenly believed that C++98 and C++03 were treated differently in GCC. According to the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Standards.html#Standards) for GCC, ansi (in C++ mode) and C++98 and C++03 refer to the same language standard. I'm unable to find the proper documentation for Clang, the [manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cxx) simply says it fully implements the C++98 standard. I'm assuming it behaves similarly to GCC.

In [Is C++03 a new version of the C++ Standard or just a Technical Corrigendum (TC) of C++98?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285777/is-c03-a-new-version-of-the-c-standard-or-just-a-technical-corrigendum-tc), [Cheers and hth. - Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8287020/3920237) says:

> C++03 (ISO C++14882:2003) is a standard in its own right, and it is
>   also "just" TC1 because it is only C++98 amended with a set of
>   corrections.
>
> You can say that C++03 is what C++98 was intended to be, the actual
>   wording of C++98 revised to make it say what it was meant to say.

Followed by the wg21's [standard's page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/standards):

> The first edition of ISO/IEC 14882 was published in 1998. A technical
>   corrigendum was approved in 2003, . *[sic]* and the standard was
>   published again as the ISO/IEC 14882:2003 edition, published
>   2003-10-16. Then the ISO/IEC 14882:2011 was published 2011-09-01.

And for completeness, the back cover of [The C++ Standard: Incorporating Technical Corrigendum No. 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470846747):

> This is technically BS ISO/IEC 14882:2003 (Second Edition) as approved
>   by all national standards bodies (such as ANSI). It is the ONLY
>   available bound version of the standard.

However, C++03 introduced *value initialization*. Of course, if modern compilers treat C++98 and C++03 mode the same, then it doesn't really make a difference.

I'm not necessarily in favor in making these tags synonyms, but I felt it was necessary to stand corrected on my mistaken assumptions.

Comment: @BartoszKP That's assuming there's someone who is aware of the differences AND had an ancient compiler. I would assume that there are far less people aware of the differences (like myself) using the tag capriciously. The tags for C++98 and C++03 seem neglected compared to C++ and the others. Perhaps they need an update.