# When should one tag C++98 and when should one tag C++03?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question is a sequel to this suggestion:

[Make C++98 and C++03 tags synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278684/make-c98-and-c03-tags-synonyms)

Clearly the suggestion is unpopular but the ensuing discussion did reveal a lot of uncertainties regarding the difference between C++98 and C++03.

So when should one tag C++98 vs C++03?

Answer (score 2):

I think that [Jeff policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/213575) about versions (this is a version of a specification)  applies:

> I would only use version tags when the question content is *irrevocably* tied to a specific version of something and can *never* be relevant to earlier versions or later versions.

So, you should use [c++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) whenever you know it's only relevant to C++98 and nothing earlier nor after, you should use [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) whenever you know is only relevant to C++03, and no C++98 or C++11. If you are not sure or it applies to more than one, just use [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

> In other words, it is perfectly sufficient to tag your question [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) when it contains c# code. You do *not* need to say that it is [c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) because it uses LINQ features. *c# is c#!*